# What type of transformer configuration?

Tags: transformer

I am curious on what type of configuration (all I know is this is related to a three phase) is this and what are the requirements for it? For example, does the kVA need to be the same? What are the other factors? Thank you.

[image: Transformers]

Comment: Your picture sucks because it doesn't depict how it's wired. It looks like a balanced 3 phase configuration: delta-delta, delta-wye, wye-delta, wye-wye. The transformers don't have to be equal. You can even have one missing in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very poor photo for this question, as the wiring isn't clear.

Looking at the HV side, it appears to be a Y configuration, as each transformer has one HV terminal connected to a feed, and the other connected to a common star point.

On the LV side, I would guess at Y again, but can't say for certain.

In terms of KVA, they would be the same for balanced loading, but if imbalance is predicted in advance they can be tailored to the load.  (The case of only a single phase being used, so only one single phase transformer deployed, being the most common.)